# Java, Struts 1.2, Json Angular JS - How can I get json response from action class to my Angular JS page?

Tags: angularjs, json, struts-1

I need a clarification on this below technology

Current technology:
Struts 1.2
Jsp
Java 
AngularJS

Currently I am trying to migrate one of my jsp page to AngularJS page which is client req.

I am trying using below code to get json response, but I unable to get the json data in my jsp page.

Question:
1) How to get a json object from the response of action class in struts?

2) Currently :
Note: one of temporary way I able to get json object in jsp using session.setAttribute() and getAttribute.. but its not rite way to do it as I just getting all my table data and put in session. apart from this any way please help..

Code :
In jsp:

```
$scope.getDataFromServer = function() {

            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/com/test/Browse.do'
            }).then (function successCallback(response) {
            var itemsDetails = JSON.parse(response);

                $scope.person = response;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });

        };
**//The above response getting as object unable to get json object.**

In action class:
public void doExecute(ActionContext ctx) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
                PersonData personData = new PersonData();//[PersonData class available]
        personData.setFirstName("Mohaideen");
        personData.setLastName("Jamil");

        String json = new Gson().toJson(personData);

                ctx.forwardToInput();
}
```

I able to get the data using session attribute like below, but it is not rite way will make me to avoid struts action and also whole table data putting in session I not sure whether it will rite way or secure way.
var data1 = '<%=session.getAttribute("jsonobjtest")%>';

Can please help me out to get the rite way to implement with struts 1.2 and angularjs? if we cannot do it help me guide me the workaround how to achieve with angularjs?

Comment: You need to actually put something into the response, either writing it directly or using a JSP to create the JSON string. For the former you'd return `null` from the action so Struts doesn't try to use its normal processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hie there from my understanding you want to get  a json object from your Java backend
here is how i do http requests in AngularJs 1.5.11

```js
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module("myapp")

.controller("HelloController", function($scope,$http){
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
            $http.get("/com/test/Browse.do").success(function(response,status){
                 //console.log(response,status); check your data 
                 $scope.person = JSON.parse(response);
            });
          }

});
```

Comment: Hi Muzingaye Moyo , Thanks for your response, I getting response as html page and status as 200 for the below code. But what I want is the json object which I have set in action class.

Comment: the code I have used In JSP:                                                                                                        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
   $http.get("/vector/audit/transactionBrowseTest.do").success(function(response,status){
   //console.log(response,status); //check your data 
   alert(response); //html as response but not getting the data I have set in action class
   alert(status); //out put 200
                 $scope.person = JSON.parse(response);
   
   });
   };

Comment: InJAVA:public void doExecute(ActionContext ctx) throws IOException,
   ServletException {
  PersonData personData = new PersonData();
  personData.setFirstName("Mohaideen");
  personData.setLastName("Jamil");

  String json = new Gson().toJson(personData);
  System.out.println(json);
  ctx.forwardToInput();
 }

Comment: hie @shaan please uncomment this line "//console.log(response,status)"  to "console.log(response,status)" and attach the screen shot of your log

Comment: Hi Muzingaye Moyo , Super man, the output of the console.log getting the {"firstName":"Mohaideen","lastName":"Jamil"}.  But How can I get that in my javascript variable? please advice.

Comment: Hi Any one can tell me that can store the console.log(response) to a var in javascript????

Comment: Hi Muzingaye Moya, your answer almost answered my question but last thing I unable to assign the value to the javascript.  console.log(response,status);  but when I assign it $scope.person = JSON.parse(response);
or alert(response); getting whole html unable use te console.log(response) value in my jsp, please help

Comment: please attach your console log

Comment: Hi Muzinagaye Moya, my code in jsp  $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
 alert("Test");
   $http.get("/vector/audit/transactionBrowseTest.do").success(function(response,status){
   alert("after response");
   console.log(response);     $scope.person  = JSON.parse(response);
   
   });
   };

Comment: my Java code:  public void doExecute(ActionContext ctx) throws IOException,
   ServletException {
  PersonData personData = new PersonData();
  personData.setFirstName("Mohaideen");
  personData.setLastName("Jamil");

  String json = new Gson().toJson(personData);
  ctx.forwardToInput();
 }    My console using f12 in browser   : SyntaxError: Invalid character   at Anonymous function (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:100:347)  at i (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:421)

Comment: am not a struts pro but  try returning null as @dave newton commented follow these links http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/obtaining-json-object-from-struts-action-response or

Comment: Hi MuzingayeMoyo, I getting the console.log(response,status) ---><html>
<head>
 <meta name="Cache-Control"  content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma"  content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires"  content="Mon, 06 Jan 1990 00:00:01 GMT">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <meta name="Copyright"   content="Copyright (c) 2005 - 2006 ACS">
 <meta name="Title"    content="TTTT Audit">
 <meta name="Author"    content="shan; moded for Audit by psubedi">
 <meta name="Language"   content="ENGLISH">

Comment: <meta name="Robots"    content="NOINDEX">

 <title>Titile</title>

 <base href="http://111.111.222.111:10022/sss/"> 
 <link href="/com/sss/app/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="/com/sss/app/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href='/images/favicon.ico' > 
 <link rel="ICON" href=/animated_favicon1.gif' type="image/gif" >

 
 
</head>
<body bottomma

Comment: Above one I getting as response of console.log, how to get the value of the json object or string I setted in?? please advice

Comment: it seems like you are not returning a json object from your server but html.the angularjs part works fine